Visual Studio 2022 C#: Cannot build project from *.sln file
On an online course I tasked with an exercise, it was the pretty simple exercise, but I have made it difficult to complete...

I have created GitHub repository, with Readme.md file and nothing more: https://github.com/frostysh/EXERCISE03_YPARKHOMENKO_CSHARPPRO_HILLEL.git
The I have cloned my remote repository to local machine, and created a new branch in which I wanted to do all work, and then merge it into a main branch on remote repository via Pull-Request.

On local machine I created some files "Program.cs", "User.cs", and so on. And I have discovered that my automatic syntax error checks is no works. More than that, project refuses to build... So I copypasted and modified files from some other projects to this project starts to work properly.

project.assets.json file from /obj/ in the root directory (I created obj-drectory too)

    {
      "version": 3,
      "targets": {
        "net8.0": {}
      },
      "libraries": {},
      "projectFileDependencyGroups": {
        "net8.0": []
      },
      "packageFolders": {
        "C:\\Users\\F021\\.nuget\\packages\\": {}
      },
      "project": {
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "restore": {
          "projectUniqueName": "C:\\Users\\F021\\source\\repos\\HILLEL_PRIVATE_SCHOOL_CSHARPRO_EXERCISE03_CONSOLE_PROGRAM_WITH_OBJECTS\\EXERCISE03_YPARKHOMENKO_CSHARPPRO_HILLEL.csproj",
          "projectName": "HILLEL_PRIVATE_SCHOOL_CSHARPPRO_EXERCISE03_CONSOLE_PROGRAM_WITH_OBJECTS",
          "projectPath": "C:\\Users\\F021\\source\\repos\\HILLEL_PRIVATE_SCHOOL_CSHARPRO_EXERCISE03_CONSOLE_PROGRAM_WITH_OBJECTS\\EXERCISE03_YPARKHOMENKO_CSHARPPRO_HILLEL.csproj",
          "packagesPath": "C:\\Users\\F021\\.nuget\\packages\\",
          "outputPath": "C:\\Users\\F021\\source\\repos\\HILLEL_PRIVATE_SCHOOL_CSHARPRO_EXERCISE03_CONSOLE_PROGRAM_WITH_OBJECTS\\obj\\",
          "projectStyle": "PackageReference",
          "configFilePaths": [
            "C:\\Users\\F021\\AppData\\Roaming\\NuGet\\NuGet.Config",
            "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\NuGet\\Config\\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Offline.config"
          ],
          "originalTargetFrameworks": [
            "net8.0"
          ],
          "sources": {
            "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\NuGetPackages\\": {},
            "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json": {}
          },
          "frameworks": {
            "net8.0": {
              "targetAlias": "net8.0",
              "projectReferences": {}
            }
          },
          "warningProperties": {
            "warnAsError": [
              "NU1605"
            ]
          },
          "restoreAuditProperties": {
            "enableAudit": "true",
            "auditLevel": "low",
            "auditMode": "direct"
          }
        },
        "frameworks": {
          "net8.0": {
            "targetAlias": "net8.0",
            "imports": [
              "net461",
              "net462",
              "net47",
              "net471",
              "net472",
              "net48",
              "net481"
            ],
            "assetTargetFallback": true,
            "warn": true,
            "frameworkReferences": {
              "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
                "privateAssets": "all"
              }
            },
            "runtimeIdentifierGraphPath": "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\sdk\\8.0.204/PortableRuntimeIdentifierGraph.json"
          }
        }
      }
    }


I created *.csproj file manually too.

    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    
        <PropertyGroup>
            <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
            <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
            <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
            <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        </PropertyGroup>
    
    </Project>


I also created *.sln file with help of console program dotnet new sln --name MySlnName


    Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
    # Visual Studio Version 17
    VisualStudioVersion = 17.0.31903.59
    MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
    Global
        GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
            Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
            Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
        EndGlobalSection
        GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
            HideSolutionNode = FALSE
        EndGlobalSection
    EndGlobal



My project's root directory looks like that:
RootFolder

But the project only works in this mode - *.csproject selected in debug menu (screenshot from MSV Studio): StartWithoutDebug *.csproj
And the project does not work in this mode - *.sln selected in debug menu: StartWithoutDebugging *.sln
I think if I will finish the work, and a teacher will clone my remote repository and try to build and launch the project, it will not work. HOW to fix it?
Thank to all for the future answers.

Copying files from other projects is not the correct way to start a project in C# with Visual Studio. If you are using Visual Studio create a new project using a project template (for example, a new C# console project). This will also create a solution for you with the necessary assets to build and run and you should be able to build and run immediately. Then continue to add your code files or edit the existing code files as needed and continue with your project. More information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-new-project

But I want to save my commits, which I have made in the branch described above.

You can delete all the files in your repository (except ReadMe.md) and commit to "clean out" the repository. Your commits will be saved. Then start again. I'm not sure what you intend to do with these commits as they are mostly a broken project The only thing you need to worry about saving is any code logic you have written that is specific to your project (class files or code you added to program.cs).

If I will do what described in your post Mr. topsail, then I will create a new solution, and then via git-console (because MSV Studio will not allow it) somehow to push all that initial project files from "a clean solution" into remote repository? And then clone it back again and start to work? Can you specify how it performs? Actually I do not want to lose history of commits and I do not want to send again invites for collaborators on new repository...

Hooray!!! The cursed magic happens! It works!
I just need to use dotnet sln add EXERCISE03_YPARKHOMENKO_CSHARPPRO_HILLEL.csproj, phew... I need to learn cursed by the nine hells default DOTNET programs package. Form now I can post the source code inside my *.sln file, which looks properly. You can compare before and after sln-program finished work.

    Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
    # Visual Studio Version 17
    VisualStudioVersion = 17.0.31903.59
    MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
    Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "EXERCISE03_YPARKHOMENKO_CSHARPPRO_HILLEL", "EXERCISE03_YPARKHOMENKO_CSHARPPRO_HILLEL.csproj", "{155BCC83-FEE6-4808-939C-81557170C5E6}"
    EndProject
    Global
        GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
            Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
            Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
        EndGlobalSection
        GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
            HideSolutionNode = FALSE
        EndGlobalSection
        GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
            {155BCC83-FEE6-4808-939C-81557170C5E6}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
            {155BCC83-FEE6-4808-939C-81557170C5E6}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
            {155BCC83-FEE6-4808-939C-81557170C5E6}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
            {155BCC83-FEE6-4808-939C-81557170C5E6}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        EndGlobalSection
    EndGlobal


Now it works 'out of the box', just double-click on sln-file, and I hope it will work on my teacher's machine too...
